# How to use next-auth with github and prisma

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am currently trying to configure next auth to work together with GitHub as a provider.
My setup is the following:

[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Providers from "next-auth/providers"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        Providers.GitHub({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        }),
        Providers.Email({
            server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        }),
    ],
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
})
```

My prisma schema looks like this:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["referentialActions"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?
  access_token       String?
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?
  session_state      String?
  oauth_token_secret String?
  oauth_token        String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

When I try to login using GitHub as a provider it correctly connects me to GitHub and I can authorize the application but after that I get an error in the console:

```
[next-auth][error][prisma__get_user_by_provider_account_id_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#prisma__get_user_by_provider_account_id_error PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    providerId_providerAccountId: {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      providerId: 'github',
      providerAccountId: 13868008
    }
  },
  select: {
    user: true
  }
}

Unknown arg `providerId_providerAccountId` in where.providerId_providerAccountId for type AccountWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `provider_providerAccountId`? Available args:
type AccountWhereUniqueInput {
  id?: String
  provider_providerAccountId?: AccountProviderProviderAccountIdCompoundUniqueInput
}


    at Document.validate (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:35195:19)
    at PrismaClient._executeRequest (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37530:17)
    at consumer (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37475:23)
    at C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37477:47
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js:189:9)
    at PrismaClient._request (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37477:25)
    at request (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37580:77)
    at Object.then (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37595:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  clientVersion: '2.30.3'
}
[next-auth][error][oauth_callback_handler_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error Error:
Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    providerId_providerAccountId: {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      providerId: 'github',
      providerAccountId: 13868008
    }
  },
  select: {
    user: true
  }
}

Unknown arg `providerId_providerAccountId` in where.providerId_providerAccountId for type AccountWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `provider_providerAccountId`? Available args:
type AccountWhereUniqueInput {
  id?: String
  provider_providerAccountId?: AccountProviderProviderAccountIdCompoundUniqueInput
}


    at Document.validate (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:35195:19)
    at PrismaClient._executeRequest (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37530:17)
    at consumer (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37475:23)
    at C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37477:47
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js:189:9)
    at PrismaClient._request (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37477:25)
    at request (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37580:77)
    at Object.then (C:\Users\tfr\Projects\employee-nextjs-gitlab\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:37595:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  name: 'GetUserByProviderAccountIdError'
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/nextauthjs/adapters/issues/219#issuecomment-917958150 -- there's a mismatch between the NextAuth documentation and newer versions of Prisma

Answer (score 2):

You can try modifying the prisma scheme to this:

```
model User {
  id                    String     @id @default(uuid())
  name                  String
  email                 String?    @unique
  emailVerified         DateTime?   @map("email_verified")
  image                 String?
  createdAt             DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt             DateTime   @updatedAt
  accounts              Account[]
  sessions              Session[]
  @@map("users")
}
model Account {
  id                 String    @id @default(cuid())
  userId              String    @map("user_id")
  type                 String?
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String    @map("provider_account_id")
  token_type         String?
  refresh_token      String?   @db.Text
  access_token       String?   @db.Text
  expires_at         Int?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String? @db.Text
  createdAt          DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime  @updatedAt
  user               User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@map("accounts")
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  userId       String?  @map("user_id")
  sessionToken String   @db.Text @map("session_token") @unique
  accessToken  String?  @db.Text @map("access_token")
  expires      DateTime
  user         User?     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt

  @@map("sessions")
}

model VerificationRequest {
  id         String   @id @default(cuid())
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

The new official nexth auth prisma adapter is broke. You can find more info about this issue here:
https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/3815

Answer (score 0):

`providerAccountId` is a string in `schema.prisma` and you're passing in a number as per the error, maybe that's causing an issue?

Comment: Thanks for the help i tried it out and changed the id to an int but it didnt work it still threw the same error but now saying the id is int.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve some problem.
My problem resolved add @@map("accounts") in Account schema
And In fact you can have only 1 account in User collection, and that is the Gihub or Google SignIn for this user.
If you already logined by Google, Github auth will be return error

This is my Prisma schema file,

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                 String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId             String @db.ObjectId
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String  @map("provider_account_id")
  refresh_token      String? @db.String
  access_token       String? @db.String
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.String
  session_state      String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@map("accounts")
}

model User {
  id              String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name            String?
  email           String?   @unique
  emailVerified   DateTime?
  image           String?
  hashedPassword  String?
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime @updatedAt
  favoriteIds     String[] @db.ObjectId

  accounts        Account[]
  listings        Listing[]
  reservations    Reservation[]
}

model Listing {
  id              String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title           String
  description     String
  imageSrc        String
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
  category        String
  roomCount       Int
  bathroomCount   Int
  guestCount      Int
  locationValue   String
  userId          String @db.ObjectId
  price           Int

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  reservations Reservation[]
}

model Reservation {
  id              String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId          String @db.ObjectId
  listingId       String @db.ObjectId  
  startDate       DateTime
  endDate         DateTime
  totalPrice      Int
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now())

  user            User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  listing         Listing @relation(fields: [listingId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```